# extract private key from pkcs12 sotre

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa

I have pkcs12 keystore(.p12) which contains multiple private key entries(3 entries) I want to extract only one key from this store and use that key to decrypt a file(which encrypted by a public key)
Are there any way to extract one key from the store via openssl by using key alias??

Comment: I need this too. Because there are no complete answers I suppose it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command to extract the private key from your PKCS12 container:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in yourP12File.pfx -nocerts -out privateKey.pem
```

Comment: I have used this command but it will add all three keys to .pem file. I want to extract only one key from .p12 file(my be using alias)

Comment: @eranga and if you open the output file and separate the keys from their BEGIN PRIVATE KEY and END PRIVATE KEY headers?

Comment: Ya, I have copied that content(between BEGIN and END) and saved into another .pem file and tried to decrypt. But it didn't work

Comment: Extracting just one key from the file may result in different localKeyID value, but it should work. You probably did not extract the correct part.